# Develop Saliency Map from saliency features

Tags: image, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am a novice in image processing and pursuing a project for image segmentation.
As described in the paper: Cluster Based Co-saliency Detection [Link to pdf of paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel7/83/4358840/06508944.pdf)

I have extracted the contrast cues and spatial cues for single image. Yet how do i actually apply these values to the image to get the saliency map ?
I am not able to visualize how these values will get reflected on the pixels to generate the saliency map. If possible, could you please explain it with a simple example.

Link to image that contains the contrast cue formula, spatial cue formula, formula to combine the saliency cues, algorithm to process a single image and sample output along with legend for notations in the formulae.[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjUl9.jpg)

Comment: Saliency map is basically the density locations of the features you extracted. The easiest way is, you put these features on an empty image and blur it. This way you will get the saliency map.

Comment: The paper states to cluster the image pixels into 6 clusters. Then contrast and spatial cues for each cluster are calculated. So basically two arrays of six elements each corresponding to contrast and spatial cue of each cluster. How should i reflect these values on to the image?

Comment: I don't have access to that paper. Can you provide sample image and/or sample cluster set?

Comment: @Ozcan I have edited the question and added additional material for those who cannot access the paper. would you need some more information?